# Spaces in foldername causing fail in batch processing of sub-directories listed in text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip

My ultimate goal is to individually zip subfolders of a main folder in one swoop from the top directory. So imagine this structure

```
Top-Folder
  -Bob
    --Folder-1
  -Steve
    --Folder-1
    --Folder-2
  -Tim
    --Folder-1
```

From Top-Folder, I'd like to run a batch script that individually zips up each of the sub folders. So in the above example, I'd have four zip files, for each of those sub folders. They would reside alongside the original folders.

folder-1.zip (from Bob)

folder-1.zip (from Steve)

folder-2.zip (from Steve)

folder-1.zip (from Tim)

I have this so far:

```
    if exist list.txt del list.txt
    if exist subfolders.txt del subfolders.txt
    REM create list of all users (top folders)
    dir "F:\Top-Folder" /AD /B >list.txt
    REM create list of all subfolders
    for /F "delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do dir %%i /AD /S /B >> subfolders.txt
    REM now you have all subfolders in subfolders.txt so you can zip them one by one
    for /F "delims=" %%X in (subfolders.txt) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

With simple test folder names this is successful. However with my real folder names, whilst list.txt is generated with the top folder names, subfolders.txt is not created and ergo the zipping can't happen.

Examples of the real folder structure/names:

2005-05-11 - Tappehallerne, Copenhagen/[AUD #1] MD(M) - CDR(1)

2005-05-11 - Tappehallerne, Copenhagen/[PRO #1b] HDTV

What do I need to change to have the subfolder names written to the second text file for the rest of the script to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do dir "%%i" /AD /S /B >> subfolders.txt
```

You need to "quote the name" otherwise `dir` looks for "quote" and "the" and "name"